# Proximal operator of the $L^1$ norm, constrained to $x\ge0$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, regularization, proximal-operators

A standard variational problem (arising, e.g., in imaging) reads

$$ \operatorname{argmin}_x \frac{1}{2}\Vert Ax - y\Vert ^2 + \Vert x\Vert_1 $$

where the $1$-norm serves as a sparsifying regularizer. In this case, I can clearly apply a forward-backward algorithm, since the fidelity is smooth and the regularizer is proximable.

**My question:** what if instead I have

$$ \operatorname{argmin}_x \frac{1}{2}\Vert Ax - y\Vert ^2 + \Vert x\Vert_1 + \iota_{\ge0}(x)$$

i.e. a positivity constraint on the variable entries (say, $x$ is an image and pixels have positive values)?

If I want to apply forward backward again, I should find explicitly the prox operator of $\Vert x\Vert_1 + \iota_{\ge0}(x)$, which amounts to solve the **constrained** problem

$$ \operatorname{argmin}_{x \ge 0} \Vert x \Vert_1 + \frac{1}{2\tau}\Vert x - \bar{x} \Vert^2 $$

Does anyone have hints on how to do that?

Comment: With the restriction $x \ge 0$, the map $x \mapsto \|x\|_1$ is linear. And you can solve this problem coefficient-wise.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't see that, thank you